# Doing math on the linux command line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a log file from a web server which looks like this;

```
1908 462
232 538
232 520
232 517
```

My task is to total column 1 and column 2 in a bash script. My desired output is;

```
2604 2037
```

I know of `awk` or `sed` which could go a long way to solving my problem but I can't fathom how to actually do it. I've trawled examples on Google but haven't turned up anything useful. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '{a += $1; b += $2} END { print a " " b }' foo.log
```

(Note the complete lack of error checking.)

**EDIT :**

Ok, here's a version with error checking:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ok = 1 } { if (/^ *[0-9]+ +[0-9]+ *$/) { a += $1; b += $2 } else { ok = 0; exit 1 } } END { if (ok) print a, b }' foo.log
```

If you don't want to accept leading or trailing blanks, delete the two `" *"`s in the if statement.

But this is big enough that it probably shouldn't be a one-liner:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    ok = 1
}

{
    if (/^ *[0-9]+ +[0-9]+ *$/) {
        a += $1
        b += $2
    }
    else {
        ok = 0
        exit 1
    }
}

END {
    if (ok) print a, b
}
```

There's still no overflow or underflow checking, and it assumes that there will be no signs.  The latter is easy enough to fix; the former would be more difficult.  (Note that awk uses floating-point internally; if the sum is big enough, it could quietly lose precision.)

Comment: `END { print a " " b }` can also be written as `END { print a,b }`. Since `OFS` by default is " ". It should work too.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. Wizard. I will accept answer when SO lets me. What errors should I be checking for, extra or missing columns?

Comment: @Tak: Most errors will just result in awk assuming the number is 0.  If you're sure the log file contains correct data, you can probably get away without checking, at some risk of meaningless results.  It's not clear whether *extra* columns are an error.  Missing columns (including empty lines) could be.  Other possible problems are words that aren't valid numbers, and numeric overflow or underflow.  Dealing with all possible errors could easily make your script ten times as long.  Decide whether it's worth it.

Comment: @Tak: One simple check would be `egrep -c '^[0-9]+ +[0-9]+$' foo.log`.  This prints the number of lines that contain something *other than* a decimal integer, followed by one or more spaces, followed by a decimal integer (with no leading or trailing blanks).  If the result is 0, the input is ok (barring overflow).  The error check is independent of the processing, which may or may not be a good thing.  Oh, and are signed numbers (`+123`, `-42`) permitted?  If so, the `awk` command can stay as it is, but the `grep` error check will have to be modified.

Comment: Ah that's great, thanks for the heads up. Signing isn't likely (bandwidth logs from nginx). I'll keep the regex in the script just in case. It compiles, ship it!

Comment: @Tak: Make sure you're checking the *output* of the `egrep -c` command, not its status.  Or better, use `egrep -q` rather than `egrep -s` and check the status rather than the output.  Be sure to test it with both valid and invalid inputs; getting the condition right is moderately tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
awk '{a+=$1;b+=$2} END {print a, b}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-awk alternative for you:

```
echo $( cut -f 1 -d " " log_file | tr '\n' + | xargs -I '{}' echo '{}'0 | bc ) $( cut -f 2 -d " " log_file | tr '\n' + | xargs -I '{}' echo '{}'0 | bc )
```

Make sure you replace log_file with your own file and that file does not have any extra or unnecessary new lines. If you have such lines then we would need to filter those out using a command like the following:

```
grep -v "^\s*$" log_file
```

Answer (score 0):

These might work for you:

```
sed ':a;N;s/ \(\S*\)\n\(\S*\) /+\2 \1+/;$!ba;s/ /\n/p;d' file | bc | paste -sd' '
```

or

```
echo $(cut -d' ' -f1 file | paste -sd+ | bc) $(cut -d' ' -f2 file| paste -sd+ |bc)
```